# modify php oop mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, oop, for-loop

Hey, so thanks to the help earlier, I now have a great function for querying a specific row of data.

```
    class Posts{

      public static function singleQuery($table, $value){

        return mysql_fetch_object(
           mysql_query("select * from $table where id=$value"), __CLASS__);

      }

    }

$set = Posts::singleQuery('settings', '1');
echo $post->title;
```

I was hoping to modify this so it queries the following:

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 3"
```

and then create an 'echo loop' or a foreach type of deal on my view/index page. Something like:

```
foreach ($a as $b){  
    echo "yadda"  
}
```

I hope this makes sense..

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 3"), __CLASS__);

while($object = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
   // each round of while has the next line in $object
   $return[] = $object;
}

return $return;
```

...

```
$array = Posts::multipleQuery(...);
foreach($array AS $row) {
   echo $row->title;
}
```

Comment: I dont want the echo to be part of the function. I want to decide how to display it later on in the view.

Comment: Ok that looks right. Now on my index page would I just do a while loop, and grab the return?

Comment: I wrapped it inside a function "public static function multipleQuery(){"